# How to set scree plot scale as same as principal components?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse, pca

I used this command line to make a Scree plot in which the first dimension shows most of the variation.

```
res.pca <- prcomp(log2(src1+1), scale. = TRUE)
res.pca
plot1 <- fviz_eig(res.pca)
plot1
```

[image]

Here is SD of the samples (36 samples):

```
Standard deviations (1, .., p=36):
 [1] 5.95582467 0.28407652 0.26522238 0.20868660 0.20012316 0.16888365 0.15432002 0.14181776 0.13427364
[10] 0.13116676 0.11774602 0.11533978 0.11221367 0.10495140 0.10142414 0.09890213 0.09604759 0.09339936
[19] 0.09077357 0.08893056 0.08650105 0.08548026 0.08308853 0.08097912 0.07497496 0.07413417 0.07224579
[28] 0.07124431 0.06996434 0.06759544 0.06335228 0.06141117 0.06091347 0.05944077 0.05849182 0.05754510
```

and my PCA plot is:

[image]

I want a help to know that how I can plot the Scree plot in a way that dimensions of the Scree plot to be in the same percentage of the PCA plot `(e.g. PC1 <- 15.55% and PC2 <- 13.82%)`?

Comment: thank you for your reply, the answer is ```0.9853291```

Comment: How was the PCA plot made?

Comment: for PCA I transform my data and then put them in log2 scale                             ```src2 <- as.data.frame(t(src1))
prcmp <- prcomp(log2(src2[,-1]+1))
pc.x <- 1
pc.y <- 2
cnt.x <- mean(prcmp$x[,pc.x])
cnt.y <- mean(prcmp$x[,pc.y])
autoplot(prcmp, data = src2, colour = 'Groups', x=1, y=2) +
  geom_point(x=cnt.x, y=cnt.y, colour="red", size=5)```

Comment: and for the Scree plot, I mentioned the code in the question above.

Comment: why did you exclude the 1st column in the second pca, and also choose not to scale? If you do fviz_eig(prcmp) it would give you the scree plot with the same % variance explained

Comment: The first column of data frame is row names, (not row index)

Comment: Should I do scaling? And how I can set the same scale or percentage peresentation same between Scree and PCA plot?

Comment: I write an example below for you, it should work with your data. It's up to you whether to scale or not. If magnitude of the columns is important, don't scale. I see that you have already taken the log.. might be better not to scale

Comment: And should I exclude the scaling in making the Scree plot? I have it in my script ```res.pca <- prcomp(log2(src1+1), scale. = TRUE)```

Comment: Yes, if don't scale for PCA plot, use the same pca results for the scree plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, in your case you need to bind your information about groups to the PC dataframe:

```
library(ggfortify)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

set.seed(111)
data = mtcars
# we make up a group here
data$group = sample(letters[1:3],nrow(data),replace=TRUE)

res.pca = prcomp(log2(data[,-ncol(data)]+1))
autoplot(res.pca,data=data,col="group")
```

[image]

Then use the same pca to make the scree:

```
#variance explained
varExp = (100*res.pca$sdev^2)/sum(res.pca$sdev^2)
varDF = data.frame(Dimensions=1:length(varExp),
varExp=varExp)

ggplot(varDF,aes(x=Dimensions,y=varExp)) + geom_point() + 
geom_col(fill="steelblue") + geom_line() + 
theme_bw() + scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:nrow(varDF)) + 
ylim(c(0,100)) + ylab("Perc variance explained")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comment, it helped a lot. I just remembered to ask what is the best way to know which elements or row names (in the first column of the data frame) drive specific sample? If you see my PCA plot two red dots are at the bottom and separated, I want to know which row names are causing this?? THANKS

Comment: you look at the loadings, prcmp$rotation in your case, since the two points are -ve extremes of PC2, you will do sort(prcmp$rotation[,"PC2"]) and you can look at the first few entries.. these are the genes that contribute to the negative

Comment: Yes with your code I get the rows and their related values but no gene name appears (as it is obvious that I removed the first column for PCA plot) but How to bring up the gene names?

Comment: set the rownames of the data.frame to be the gene names. rownames(df) = df[,1] ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understood your answer ```rownames(df) = df[,1]``` correctly. Since loading are in ```prcmp``` which doesn't inclued any row name, how can combine your code with ```prcmp```?

Comment: you redo the prcomp.. the loadings will contain the rownames now

Comment: it didn't work. my data frame is transformed using ```src2 <- as.data.frame(t(src1))``` and the plotted with ```prcmp <- prcomp(log2(src2[,-1]+1))``` so when I ran ```colnames(prcmp) = src2[,1]``` it gives this error for me ::: ```Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("control", "control", "control",  : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions```

Comment: ```8.380003e-04``` is the last value among the sorted values, but the two dots (samples) are above  ```-0.6```  in the PCA plot. I know this ```8.380003e-04``` is for genes, but then this value is out of range in the plot, CONFUSED :////

Comment: it should be rownames(src2) = src[,1]... perhaps it would help if you go through same introductions to pca first.. http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/112-pca-principal-component-analysis-essentials/, can save you a lot of frustration

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help